# What happens if you get the pink coin at the end of the tutorial level?

Tags: super-mario-run

There is a single pink coin at the end of the tutorial level, after wall jumping to the top of a set of pipes.

You can't revisit this level without uninstalling and reinstalling the game (as far as I can tell).

Do you get anything special for collecting this coin?

Comment: Ah, you can replay the tutorial from the Tour screen, press How to Play in the bottom right. Still can't get that pink coin though...

Comment: I got the pink coin in the tutorial. It goes "jingle", and then the tutorial ends :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Pink Coin](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/975797) is a bonus coin. A pink coin is worth 10 regular coins at the end of each level, which will allow you to unlock more things.

From the above site:

> [image]

The pink coin at the end of the tutorial does not do anything special other than this.